# Datatables headers not full width on page load

Tags: javascript, datatables, header, modal-dialog

When loading my web application page with datatables, the datatable is loaded but the `<thead>` row is not full width of the table.

After editing the data, or searching in the datatable search, the header jumps to full width. See picture.

Any solution or workaround for this?

Screenshot of datatable:

[image: Screenshot of datatable]

My normal datatables are fine, but this one is loaded within a modal. 
Code modal:

```
<!-- Get selected shops modal -->
<div id="SelectedShopsModal" class="infomodal">
    <div class="shops-content">
        <h2><span class="closeModalSelectedShops">&times;</span> <?php echo lang('Shops'); ?></h2>
        <div class="detailblock">
            <table id="DataListTableSelectedShops" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <th class="OE"><?php echo lang('Shop_No'); ?></th>
                    <th class="OE"><?php echo lang('Shop_Name'); ?></th>
                    <th class="OE"><?php echo lang('Shop_District'); ?></th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php foreach($selected_shops as $shop){
                        echo "<tr><td>" . $shop['Shop'] . "</td><td>" . $shop['Name'] . "</td><td>" . $shop['District'] . "</td></tr>";
                    } ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <br /><button class="closeBtnSelectedShops btn red"><?php echo lang('Close'); ?></button>
            <button class="btn red" onclick="delete_oneshots();"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo lang('Delete_shops'); ?></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My javascript that is used in the footer of my page:

```
//datatable to display all selected shops on detail page
selectedshoptable = $('#DataListTableSelectedShops').DataTable( {
    "dom": "Bfrtip",
    "scrollY": "300px",
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bInfo" : false,
    "fields": [ {
        label: "Shopnr",
        name: "Shop"
    }, {
        label: "Shopname:",
        name: "Name"
    }, {
        label: "District",
        name: "District"
    }],
    "buttons":[{
        extend: 'selectAll',
        text: '<?php echo lang('Select_all'); ?>',
        className: 'btn red'
    }, {
        text: '<?php echo lang('Select_none'); ?>',
        className: 'btn red',
        action: function () {
            selectedshoptable.rows().deselect();
        }
    }],
    "language": {
        "zeroRecords": "<?php echo lang('Nothing_found'); ?>",
        "infoEmpty": "<?php echo lang('No_records_available'); ?>",
        "search":"<?php echo lang('Search'); ?>",
        "buttons": {"selectNone": "Select none"}
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please post your code here?

Comment: Hi David, my codes are added.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

#### CAUSE

Your table is hidden initially which prevents jQuery DataTables from adjusting column widths.

#### SOLUTION

- If table is in the collapsible element, you need to adjust headers when collapsible element becomes visible.

  For example, for Bootstrap Collapse plugin:

  ```
  $('#myCollapsible').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
     $($.fn.dataTable.tables(true)).DataTable()
        .columns.adjust();
  });
  ```
- If table is in the tab, you need to adjust headers when tab becomes visible.

  For example, for Bootstrap Tab plugin:

  ```
  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e){
     $($.fn.dataTable.tables(true)).DataTable()
        .columns.adjust();
  });
  ```

Code above adjusts column widths for all tables on the page. See [`columns().adjust()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust%28%29) API methods for more information.

#### RESPONSIVE, SCROLLER OR FIXEDCOLUMNS EXTENSIONS

If you're using Responsive, Scroller or FixedColumns extensions, you need to use additional API methods to solve this problem.

- If you're using Responsive extension, you need to call [`responsive.recalc()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/responsive.recalc%28%29) API method **in addition** to [`columns().adjust()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust%28%29) API method. See [Responsive extension – Incorrect breakpoints](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-column-width-issues-with-bootstrap-tabs/#example2) example.
- If you're using Scroller extension, you need to call [`scroller.measure()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/scroller.measure%28%29) API method **instead of** [`columns().adjust()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust%28%29) API method. See [Scroller extension – Incorrect column widths or missing data](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-column-width-issues-with-bootstrap-tabs/#example3) example.
- If you're using FixedColumns extension, you need to call [`fixedColumns().relayout()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/fixedColumns%28%29.relayout%28%29) API method **in addition** to [`columns().adjust()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust%28%29) API method. See [FixedColumns extension – Incorrect column widths](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-column-width-issues-with-bootstrap-tabs/#example4) example.

#### LINKS

See [jQuery DataTables – Column width issues with Bootstrap tabs](http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-column-width-issues-with-bootstrap-tabs) for solutions to the most common problems with columns in jQuery DataTables when table is initially hidden.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added selectedshoptable.columns.adjust(); to the JS function of my modal and it works fine.