# Bootstrap table not aligned until resize of window

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am using datatables and bootstrap to have tables on my page.

When I show the table, the headers and the rows are not aligned, the columns are smaller for the header but the different rows are taking all the space of the window.

[image: Not fine]

But if I resize a little bit my window then everything is fine again and the columns of the header and the rows are well aligned.

[image: After resizing of the window]

Comment: Please provide a fiddle or other demo it's difficult to guess what's going on / wrong here. What I can assume is, that a JS `resize` event adds some style or class to the header or its surrounding `<div>`. Depending how the table markup looks like.

Comment: That question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46160726/3549014) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42178701/3549014).